# Trouble retrieving data laravel4(oneToMany)

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, laravel

Okay so I just started learning Laravel and its fantastic. I just got stuck trying to retrive all the post from a user. Here is my code

models/User.php

```
public function posts()
{
    $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

models/Post.php

```
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

controller/UserController.php

```
public function getUserProfile($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.index', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

views/user/index.blade.php

```
<div class="show-post">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $user->posts }}</lo>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I also tried:

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
     <li>{{$post->post}}</li>
@endforeach
```

So im having trouble displaying the post for each specific user. Thank you.

Comment: please share tables schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `$user->posts` returns a collection of `Post` model so when you try this

```
{{ $user->posts }}
```

`Laravel` tries to echo that collection object which is not possible. You may try `foreach` loop instead:

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->somepropertyname }}
@endforeach
```

It's also possible to do something like this:

```
// Get first post->somepropertyname
{{ $user->posts->first()->somepropertyname }}

// Get last post->somepropertyname
{{ $user->posts->last()->somepropertyname }}

// Get first post->somepropertyname (same as first)
{{ $user->posts->get(0)->somepropertyname }}

// Get second post->somepropertyname from collection
{{ $user->posts->get(1)->somepropertyname }}

// Get the post->somepropertyname by id (post id) 2
{{ $user->posts->find(2)->somepropertyname }}
```

Also you may use eager loading like this (better):

```
$user = User::with('posts')->where('username', '=', $username)->first();
```

You may like [this article](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object#.U355K_mSySo) about `Cocllection`.

**Update:** Also use `return` in model methods, like:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

Comment: thank you that article is very handy and ive been really reading over the docs which is helping a lot I can't give u a check since its not solved and Im brand new so i cant even vote you up but if it makes you feel any better you helped me lol

Comment: How it not be solved ? It should be done if you follow my answer. Waht error you see now ?

Comment: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Comment: Did you use `User::with('posts')` ? try without it but it should work if you declared the relationship as explained.

Comment: yea I copied and pasted and then added your foreach loop in the view

Comment: i figured out the problem in the models I wasn't returning my function

Comment: lmaoo I know its always the easiest mistakes that really trip you up because your thinking it's something more serious.

Comment: Yes, because my focus was not in that function because i was answering about the `Collection` handling.

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of @WereWolf- The Alpha I was able to solve it and make my code better, If you notice I forgot to return my relationship functions. example:

Notice I hadn't returned it before

models/Post.php

```
public function users()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('users');
}
```

But also the way I was querying my database was inefficient so Alpha showed me Eager Loading
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

example of controller

```
public function getUserProfile($username)
{
    $user = User::with('posts')->where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.index', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

and finally the view:

```
div class="show-post">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            {{ $post->post }}
        @endforeach
</div>
```